# stored procedure error handling

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, exception

```
i have this procedure for inserting rows in tables(sql server 2005)

CREATE PROCEDURE ans_insert
    (
    @q_desc varchar(2000),
    @sub_id int,
    @marks int,
    @ans1 varchar(1000),
    @ans varchar(1000),
    @userid varchar(15),
    @cr_date datetime

    )
    AS
    BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        DECLARE @q_id int

        insert into questions(q_desc,sub_id,marks,created_by,DT_created) values(@q_desc,@sub_id,@marks,@userid,@cr_date);
        SET @q_id = IDENT_CURRENT('questions')

        INSERT INTO answers(ans_desc,q_id,created_by,DT_created,istrue)
            VALUES( @ans1,@q_id,@userid,@cr_date,
            CASE WHEN @ans1 =@ans THEN 1 ELSE 0 END);
    COMMIT TRANSACTION

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

        DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
        DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
        DECLARE @ErrorState INT;
        DECLARE @ErrorLine INT;
        SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
        @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
        @ErrorLine=ERROR_LINE(),
        @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 


    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage,@ErrorSeverity,@ErrorState,@ErrorLine);
    END CATCH
    END
```

ans i call this from my ASP.NET form as

AnsCmd is my stored procedure command...after adding all params

```
               try
                {


                    conn.Open();

                    AnsCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    lblMsg.Visible = true;
                    lblMsg.Text = "success";
                    conn.Close();
                }
                catch (SqlException sqlex)
                {
                    lblMsg.Visible = true;
                    lblMsg.Text = sqlex.ToString();
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    lblMsg.Visible = true;
                    lblMsg.Text = ex.ToString();

                }
```

to check that raiserror is working,i changed the table name in insert from answers to answers1 which does not exist..

when executed i get error message as

**System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'answers1'. Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates that a COMMIT or ROLLBACK TRANSACTION statement is missing. Previous count = 0, current count = 1. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,......**

so is this thing working properly or m i missing something???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The batch (stored procedure) is aborting when it gets to the non-existent table (which is [deferred name resolution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190686(SQL.90).aspx)), so the ROLLBACK is not executing.

From [MSDN/BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179296(SQL.90).aspx):

> **Compile and Statement-level Recompile Errors**
>
> There are two types of errors that
> will not be handled by TRY…CATCH if
> the error occurs in the same execution
> level as the TRY…CATCH construct:
>
> - Compile errors, such as syntax errors that prevent a batch from
>   executing.
> - Errors that occur during statement-level recompilation, such as
>   object name resolution errors that
>   happen after compilation due to
>   deferred name resolution.
>
> When the batch, stored procedure, or
> trigger that contains the TRY…CATCH
> construct generates one of these
> errors, the TRY…CATCH construct does
> not handle these errors.

I suggest you add `SET XACT_ABORT ON` at the top. This will force a `ROLLBACK` on error and "tidy up".

One more thing...

```
SET @q_id = IDENT_CURRENT('questions')
```

should be

```
SET @q_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Edit:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ans_insert
    @q_desc varchar(2000),
    @sub_id int,
    @marks int,
    @ans1 varchar(1000),
    @ans varchar(1000),
    @userid varchar(15),
    @cr_date datetime
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON; -- what I do

BEGIN TRY
....
```

Comment: +1 does it also matter that BEGIN TRANSACTION is after BEGIN TRY?

Comment: @AdamRalph: no. the TXN will be started when it hits the statement where deferred name resolution fails. I pretty much do everything inside TRY/CATCH blocks

Comment: ok so if i use table name that actually exists and some error occurs during insert...then the transaction will rollback?? i.e
whatever i hv done is correct if table names are correct??--thanx

Comment: @anay: Yes, it will work. I do similar, but I always use SET XACT_ABORT ON.

Comment: fair enough. sure, TRY/CATCH it definitely a good pattern, I was just thinking that perhaps the BEGIN TRANSACTION needs to be before BEGIN TRY. In an analgous C# example, you need to declare variables before a  try{} block in order that they can be used within a catch{} block. I was thinking that this might also apply to the transaction, i.e. has to be started before BEGIN TRY to allow ROLLBACK TRANSACTION after BEGIN CATCH. If that's not the case then no worries.

Comment: @AdamRalph: your TXN handling could be anywhere, true, and you could have BEGIN inside/ROLLBACK outside. However, in this case the batch aborts and no more code is executed anyway. Which is why I suggest SET XACT_ABORT ON to force a ROLLBACK

Comment: @gbn:SET XACT_ABORT ON is written b4 Begin transaction or??

Comment: @anay: I put it on the first line, immediately at start of stored proc

Comment: @gbn:that is after create procedure and declaration of params ??

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it'll affect the exception - but some thoughts:

- would `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` be easier (and more reliable) than `IDENT_CURRENT`? `IDENT_CURRENT` can return an id from **another session** during parallel operations. Also avoid `@@IDENTITY`, which can be impacted by triggers doing `INSERT`s
- why not let the calling (.NET) code worry about the transaction? It is *far* easier (and more versatile) to manage at a higher level, either on the connection (`SqlTransaction`) or wider (`TransactionScope`)

Example `SqlTransaction` approach:

```
using(SqlTransaction tran = conn.BeginTransaction()) {
    try {
        // operations (may need to set command.Transaction = tran)
        tran.Commit();
    } catch {
        tran.Rollback();
        throw;
    }
}
```

Example `TransactionScope` approach (** must SPAN the connection **)

```
using(TransactionScope tran = new TransactionScope()) {
    // operations: note no other changes
    tran.Complete();
}
```

Comment: This assume a .net client though

Comment: @mark--i m calling this procedure in a for loop and using dataadapters at also..i tried BeginTransaction but because i hv to to look for so many conn.open and close it is getting complex for me....thanx

Comment: @gbn - I assumed only what was in the question; pretty much every client has transaction support.

Comment: `TransactionScope` removes most of this complexity, since you don't need to attach to individual commands.